# d3.js - sparql result json format for forced directed graph

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js, sparql

I have created a PHP script that executes a query against a SPARQL endpoint and puts the result in a JSON file. So far, so good. However, I also need to visualise the data I have received in a forced directed graph. This means, if I understand correctly, that I need to pass a JSON file specifying the nodes and links between them in order to get the graph like the example below (just copied and pasted the first lines to show the structure):

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
    {"name":"Napoleon","group":1}
   ]
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8}
  ]
}
```

On the other hand, from the PHP script I receive JSON results similiar to this one:

```
{"query_type":"select","result":{"rows":[{"name type":"literal","name":"Academy Award","name lang":"en"},{"name type":"literal","name":"Archive","name lang":"en"},{"name type":"literal","name":"Band","name lang":"en"},{"name type":"literal","name":"Band","name lang":"en"},{"name type":"literal","name":"Band","name lang":"en"},{"name type":"literal","name":"Believers","name lang":"en"},{"name type":"literal","name":"Believers","name lang":"en"},{"name type":"literal","name":"Believers","name lang":"en"},{"name type":"literal","name":"Believers","name lang":"en"},{"name type":"literal","name":"Believers","name lang":"en"}],"variables":["name"]},"query_time":0.15745806694031}
```

So, my question is how can i format the second one to look like the first (and to work with all kinds of results, not this one in particular) in order to use the results in d3.js. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should loop through your results to build a new array based on the old array based on the other one.

Comment: **"I need to pass a JSON file specifying the nodes and links"**  No, you don't need this to be in a separate file.  You can read your SPARQL results and then create a new Javascript Object that you pass to the d3 functions.  You don't need to a create a separate file.

Comment: Also, note that if you're using SPARQL to get data that you're going to turn into a graph, it will probably be easier if you use a CONSTRUCT query (instead of a SELECT query) to construct the actual graph that you want.  Then the translation to the D3 structure will probably be much easier.

Comment: Even if you don't use a CONSTRUCT, and you keep using a SELECT query, the example d3 input you've shown us doesn't look related at all to the example SPARQL output you've shown us.  The results you're showing us is just a list of names.  A graph needs links and connections between nodes.  Your set of results is just a list of strings.  There's not enough information to provide any kind of meaningful answer.